# Microsoft access database 2007 2010 coding error= compile error: "end if without block if"

Tags: database, ms-access

This is the code I  am using for my login screen, for the login buttton using a link from youtube but i am facing difficulty. The first line is highlighted in yellow which may suggest there is a problem with it:

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()
If IsNull(Me.TxtUsername) Then
   MsgBox "Please enter Username", vbInformation, "Username required"
   Me.TxtUsername.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
   MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password required"
   Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
   'process the job

   If (IsNull(DLookup("[Username]", "User details", "[Username] ='" & Me.TxtUsername.Value & "' And password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password"
   Else
        DoCmd.Close

        End If
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 EndIfs but only 2 Ifs.
Remove one of the Endifs.